# User in Iran can't communicate with my server in the U.S

Tags: connection

Someone on Iran is unable to connect to my service which is hosted on a server in the U.S. It seems like most other services work for them fine but mine does not.

I asked them to ping the server and the request timed out.

Also I VPN'ed into UAE and South Africa and was able to establish a connection without a problem.

Does anyone have any idea why this might not be working? I'm actively communicating with them so clearly their internet does work. Do certain countries like Iran have firewalls?

Thank you.

Comment: Yup. https://iranfocus.com/iran-general/28322-technical-glitch-brings-down-iran-firewall/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iran is using a filtering service to control the Internet usage. Some other country have firewall that block or filter request.

I would advice to not advise your customer(s) to use a VPN, as it can be against their local law to do so.

Your legal way to open to those country is really limited sadly.

Iran - It's  Telecommunication Company of Iran (TCI) that filter the Internet [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Iran).

[Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_Russia) - Its Roskomnadzor that filter the Internet.

China - It's their [Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall).